# ajax в WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Использовал уже много раз ajax запросы в WordPress. Но в последнее время заметил, что все-таки они долго выполняются. Замерил время работы скриптов таких, как wp-ajax и впоследствии wp-load. Понял, что львиная доля времени выполнения запроса ложится на них (примерно 80-85% времени). От этого и возникает вопрос, можно ли как-то уменьшить это время, не используя стандартно wp-ajax, в обход него, чем это тогда грозит? Или, может, используя его, но, может, как-то оптимизируя работу его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможности есть разные.

**Прямые ajax-запросы**

В принципе, ничто не мешает делать прямой ajax-запрос к своему обработчику php. Никакие функции WordPress при этом работать не будут, но если у вас совсем простой запрос к серверу (мне сложно даже придумать осмысленный пример), то использовать такой вариант можно. В безопасности, правда, будет дыра, но об этом ниже.

**Сокращение времени выполнения**

При обычном обращении к странице WordPress выполняет инициализацию в три этапа:

1. `/wp-load.php` - загрузка библиотеки WordPress
2. `wp();` - установка главного запроса WordPress
3. `/template-loader.php` - загрузка темы

При выполнении ajax-запроса вызывается только `/wp-load.php`, т.е. и так WP выполняет сокращённую инициализацию. Правда, не стоит забывать, что при этом подключаются все плагины. Медленная загрузка, в первую очередь, вызвана кодом плагинов. Попробуйте выполнить ajax на голом WP, и вы увидите разницу.

Так что рецепт тут такой - с помощью mu-плагина отключить (при определённых запросах!) некоторые плагины. mu-плагины загружаются раньше всех остальных, и это единственное правильное место отключения плагинов "на лету".

**Безопасность**

Система выполнения ajax-запросов в WordPress через `admin-ajax.php` придумана, в том числе, с целью обеспечения безопасности. Инициализация библиотеки позволяет использовать функции WordPress, связанные с проверкой nonce. Число, используемое один раз (Number used ONCE - nonce) - это некая метка, позволющая проверить, что запрос сделан с вашего сайта и уйти от XSRF (Cross- Site Request Forgering - межсайтовая подделка запросов). И хотя на самом деле число это используется не один раз, такая проверка ajax совершенно необходима.

Поэтому прямые запросы крайне не рекомендуются.

**TL;DR**

Оптимизируйте число плагинов, установленных на сайте, их работу при ajax - вот реальный путь сокращения времени запроса.

Comment: Отвлекся, проверил на чистой wp запросы. Ну в среднем это время 0.4сек, на работающем сайте же подавляющее большинство случаев было 0.6 - 0.7, но были так же запросы по 1сек и более (что плохо). Если сравнивать чистую и хороший вариант сейчас то не особо вижу разницы. А если чистую и худший случай разница заметна. Вобщем не знаю что и думать, хорошо это или плохо...

Comment: Почему время запросов на чистом wp стабильно, а на реальном сайте "гуляет"? Плагины. Надо выяснить, какие, и исключить.